# Polars replace_all() Refer To Capture Groups In Replacement

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

How do I refer to one of the capture groups in polars `replace_all` method in the replacement string? For example I want to replace "5m" with "5 metres". In Postgres I can do this:

```
select regexp_replace(text_col, '(\d+)m ', '\1 metres ')
from my_table
```

How could I achieve the same thing in polars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dollar sign `$` to refer to capture groups.

The supported syntax is from the regex crate: https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/

```
pl.Series(["214365"]).str.replace_all(r"(.)(.)", "$2$1")
```

```
shape: (1,)
Series: '' [str]
[
    "123456"
]
```

named capture groups example:

```
pl.Series(["214365"]).str.replace_all(r"(?<left>.)(?<right>.)", "$right$left")
```

```
shape: (1,)
Series: '' [str]
[
    "123456"
]
```